# Why is a field $A$ isomorphic to it's fractionnal field $K(A)$?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I am asked to demonstrate a field $A$ is isomorphic to it's fractionnal field $K(A)$ [it's not the notation i commonly use but i see wikipedia uses it so ,]

I tried to use different approaches but it seems i'm not sure of what's best.

I think a bit about the example of reals $R$ , constructing a isomorphism between reals and the reals fractions , seem impossible to me (I mean , in term of standard function , how could we send 0 on 0 , 1 to 1 , and be able to send elements on $\dfrac35$ as exemple , I don't really get it)

Any idea of what theorem would be the best to try to demonstrate that or , how to construct such a isomorphism ?

Francis Benjamin

Comment: Because of the construction of $K(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the map from $K(A)$ to $A$ by:
$$ \frac{a}{b} \mapsto ab^{-1} $$

Then show this map is an isomorphism and you are done!

Abit more details:

- This map is clearly surjective.
- Showing injectivity is essentially is recognizing that $ab^{-1} = a' b'^{-1}$ is the 'cross multiplication' of fractions

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: You are welcome!